# Alerts set for items sometimes will show the List name and other will not

Tags: 2013, development, email, alert

I am working on a team site collection inside sharepoint on-premises 2013. and inside a team site i have two lists one named `Assumption` while the other named `Risk Issuee`.

now i want to set some alerts on items inside the 2 lists. so i did the following:-

1. I went to Assumption list, select an item, select to set an alert for this item, as follow:-

[image]

and the email i received will be consistant with the alert subject as follow:-

```
Subject: An alert for 'Assumption: AP2' has been created
```

2. while i went to the other list named `Risk Issuee`, and i set an alert for an item inside this list as follow:-

[image]

but the email subject i will receive will be as follow:-

```
Subject: An alert for 'RI3' has been created
```

so the list name it not is showing inside the email subject. now the correct email subject should be `Subject: An alert for 'Risk Issue RI3' has been created`
so can anyone adivce what might be causing this problem ? why on some lists the Set alert email will contain the list name while on other lists it will not?